# What is the minimum engine hp needed to fly a light aircraft with an adult

Tags: wing

---

And also the wing size, propeller sizer, body size, ruder, elevator needed.

I might sound stupid; I am a beginner and I just want to these basis.

Comment: Not stupid, but way too broad of a question. You are basically asking the whole set of design priciples for a small acft.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to fly using a small engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/is-it-possible-to-fly-using-a-small-engine)

Comment: The answers to this question may be of help:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45160/can-an-ultralight-aircraft-fly-with-a-18hp-engine/45161#45161

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question to eliminate things like gliders and balloons.  Something like "What's the minimum power needed for a plane to maintain altitude in still air?"

Comment: Given that the asker mentioned wings and propellers, then surely they meant **airplanes** (powered fixed-wing); sadly the *rushed tongue in cheek answers* are never helpful and IMO should be deleted, and also the question closed until the scope in the body is narrowed down.

Comment: @ymb1 Human powered aircraft have wings, propellers, rudders, elevators, etc, as in the OP's question, but no engine.  I don't see anything "tongue in cheek" in pointing out *why* the question was too vague to answer.

Comment: @alephzero: How many times people asked about human-powered airplanes without specifying? If it's too vague, letting OP know in the comments is the way to go, not the answer box, because if it's too vague, then the answer box shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 5):

Gliders fly without any engine at all, therefore, I would say the minimum horse power required is 0.

Comment: "*Gliders fly without any engine at all*": I guess that's a simplification. Gliders need engines and fuel to become airborne, even if there are particular cases: One time flight from a hill, winch rotated by wind, etc.

Comment: It is perfectly possible for a glider to take off from a hill top with no mechanical engine or winch power, climb using the lift from the wind blowing over the hill, and land back on the same hill top for another flight.

Answer (score 3):

Hydrogen/Helium balloons fly without any engine at all, therefore, I would say the minimum horse power required is 0.